# Android TSP Hovering

Tags: android, hover

Is there any way (or any API) that we can use to check if TSP Hovering is supported by android devices?

There are listeners added in android API 14 i.e. View.OnHoverListener. But this does not show if Finger Hover is supported.

Here is [link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/floating-touch-api/77/236646?boardName=GeneralB&startId=zzzzz~http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/floating-touch-api/77/236646?boardName=GeneralB&startId=zzzzz~) which describes Samsung doesn't provide any such API.

I want generalized solution using Android APIs.

Does anyone have any idea about this or any hack ?